# while loop in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am new to bash scripting and trying to learn a few things. Here is the code I have tried:

```
n=$1
shift

echo "Printing your name $n times"
count=1
for ((i=1;i<=$n;i++))
do
    echo $@ -$i
    count='expr[$count+1]'
done

echo 'New Model'
count=1
while ["$count" -le "$n"]
do
    echo $@ -$i
    count='expr[$count+1]'
done
```

The for loop works fine, but the while loop is not printing the desired result. the Result of the for loop and while should be the same.  Could you please tell me where  I have gone wrong.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you need spaces around the brackets, so that `bash` knows that they're separate words. That is, change this:

```
while ["$count" -le "$n"]
```

to this:

```
while [ "$count" -le "$n" ]
```

Another is that this:

```
count='expr[$count+1]'
```

actually sets the variable `count` to the specific string `expr[$count+1]`. What you seem to mean is this:

```
count=$((count+1))
```

which increases the value of `count` by 1.

Comment: The `[` is actually a link to `/bin/test` (ok, in `bash` it's a builtin, but that's where it comes from).  So `[` is a word (just like `ls`) and that's why it needs the space.

Comment: @BenJackson: I think the spaces would be needed even without that; note that `[[` requires spaces as well, even though it *is* magical in other ways.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much for the info, but what I did not understand is count='expr[$count+1]' worked in for loop but did not work in while loop, can you please tell me why?  Thank you.

Comment: @surpavan: It *doesn't* work in the `for`-loop; but nothing in the `for`-loop *uses* the value of `count`, so it doesn't matter that it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 2):

another ways to increment variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1

#count=`expr $count + 1 `
#(( count++ ))
#count=$[$count + 1]
#count=$[count + 1]
#let count=count+1
#let count++
#count=$(( count + 1 ))

echo $count
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
count=1
while [ "$count" -le "$n" ]
do
echo $@ -$i
count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

there needs to be a space in the `while` condition. and the increment of `count` needs the back-quote, not a single quote, to execute the command and assign it to a variable.